# what does `args.unshift(this)` do in Vue's use.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am reading vuejs source code, and got confused by these two lines of code:

```
const args = toArray(arguments, 1)
args.unshift(this)
```

in the following snippet, why bother do this ?

```
/* @flow */

import { toArray } from '../util/index'

export function initUse (Vue: GlobalAPI) {
  Vue.use = function (plugin: Function | Object) {
    /* istanbul ignore if */
    if (plugin.installed) {
      return
    }
    // additional parameters
    const args = toArray(arguments, 1)
    args.unshift(this)
    if (typeof plugin.install === 'function') {
      plugin.install.apply(plugin, args)
    } else {
      plugin.apply(null, args)
    }
    plugin.installed = true
    return this
  }
}
```

Comment: He's throwing away the first argument and replacing it with `this`. I imagine the actual first argument is useless. Why not log it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inside of a `Vue`instance, the lines in question are in the function defined on `Vue.use` the this most likely will reference the current Vue instance.

You will have to browse the source of `toArray` to understand the first line, it might takes the arguments and returning an array from them, and maybe substracting the first argument (the 1 in `toArray(arguments, 1)` give me this impression but to be sure browse the source of that function).

But then when the call `args.unshift(this)`comes it puts the `Vue` instance as the first element of the args `array` which is then used to provide arguments to the `plugin` function.

Hope that helps ;-)

Seb